# Show that the curves of the second family are solutions of the DE

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification

Given a family of initial conditions of a differential equation $y'= f(x,y)$. Let us consider a second family with the property that at each point $p=( x,y)$ the curves of each family that pass through it intersect at the same angle $\alpha$ . Show that the curves of the second family are solutions of the DE $y'=\frac{f(x,y)+\tanα }{1−f(x,y)\tanα}$

Taking into account that the tangent of the angle $\beta$ that forms the axis $OX$ with the curve of the first family at a point $(x,y)$ is the slope $\tan(\beta)=y'=f(x,y)$.

Therefore the second curve will form an angle $\beta+\alpha$ and thus its slope will be $y'=\tan(\beta+\alpha)$:

$y'=\tan(\beta+\alpha)=\dfrac{\tan(\beta)+\tan(\alpha)}{1-\tan(\beta)\tan(\alpha)}=\dfrac{f(x ,y)+\tan(\alpha)}{1-f(x,y)\tan(\alpha)}$

Is this well demonstrated? Or the demonstration is not complete? Can you help me?

Comment: So what I did is proven wrong?

Comment: gonzalo but what would the complete demonstration be like? can you help me please? It is very difficult for me to do the demonstrations

Comment: can you solve this proof in the correct way? I don't understand Gonzalo, because for me The first family is the data. It is the set of curves that satisfy this differential equation:

$y'=f(x,y)$

The second family is the one that fulfills the property requested in the statement: "at each point $p=( x,y)$ the curves of each family that pass through it intersect at the same angle $ \alpha$. We have shown that it is the set of curves that satisfies this differential equation:

$y'=\dfrac{f(x,y)+tan(\alpha)}{1-f(x,y)tan(\alpha)}$