# Prove that $f(x,y)=xy^2$ 1. satisfies a Lipschitz condition on any rectangle R1

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Prove that $f(x,y)=xy^2$

1. satisfies a Lipschitz condition on any rectangle R1 where $a≤ x≤ b$ and $c ≤ y ≤ d; $
2. does not satisfy a Lipschitz condition on any band $a≤ x≤ b$ and
   $ −∞ ≤ y≤ ∞ $

For 1)
$|xy^2-uv^2|= |xy^2-uy^2+uy^2-uv^2|≤|xy^2-uy^2|+|uy^2-uv^2| =|y^2| |x-u|+|u| |y^2-v^2|=|y^2| |x-u|+|u| |y-v| |y + v|$

$ \cdots\leq K_2^2|x-u|+2K_1K_2|y-v|\leq L\|(x,y)-(u,v)\|_1$
where the dimensions are
$K_1=max\{|a|,|b|\}\\K_2=max\{|c|,|d|\}\\L=max\{K_2^2,2K_1K_2\}$
since $\forall\,(x,y),(u,v)\in[a,b]\times [c,d]$

For the second part $x\neq 0$:

$|f(x,n^2)-f(x,n^2+1/n)|=|x||n^4-(n^2+1/n)^2|= 2|xn||1+1/n^2|\geq 2|x|n$

which is as big as we want for $n$ big enough. That means that if we do not limit $y$ we can take $(x,y)=(x,n)$ and $(x',y')=(x, n^2+1/n)$ as close as we want but in such a way that $f(x,y)$ and $f(x',y')$ are as close far as we want.

I want to know if the proof is correct? or are there things to correct

Comment: It looks good to me! Though just a tiny detail, I believe $|f(x,n^2)-f(x,n^2+1/n)|=|xn| |2+1/n^3|$. Also, for the second part you've actually proven that $f$ isn't uniformly continuous, which is an even stronger result than was asked. For Lipschitz continuity, it would have been sufficient to show that $\frac{|f(x,n)-f(x,0)|}{|n-0|}$ is unbounded for example.

Comment: Thank you, can you give me your point of view with this demonstration? I don't know if it is complete, or if you can help me demonstrate this please

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4770889/show-that-the-curves-of-the-second-family-are-solutions-of-the-de?noredirect=1#comment10135927_4770889